# Is it possible to modify postgresql.conf using pg_ctl?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am programmatically starting PostgreSQL instances using `pg_ctl init` and `pg_ctl start`. I need to modify the configuration in postgresql.conf (specifically `listen_addresses`, and maybe some other values) and am trying to find a way to do this using `pg_ctl`, if possible. The documentation for [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-pg-ctl.html) and [initdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-initdb.html) make no mention of this. The section on [Setting Parameters](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/config-setting.html) states that I can pass parameters to the `postgres` command, but in my case I am using `pg_ctl` to start the server process. Is this possible with `pg_ctl` or other command line tool included with PostgreSQL 9.5?

Comment: Why do you need this to be done through `pg_ctl`? Why can't you edit the file or use  `alter system`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the documentation page for `pg_ctl` carefully shows you what happens with the stuff you pass to it using `-o`:

> `-o options`
>
> Specifies options to be passed directly to the postgres command; multiple option invocations are appended.

So you can, for example, do the following:

```
pg_ctl -D {your data directory} -o "-c listen_addresses='*'" start
```

where the whole double-quoted expression is passed to `postgres` (for details, see [its own documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html)).

As [Craig Ringer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7788/craig-ringer) pointed out in a comment, it might be easier and, more importantly, has a lasting effect if you change these parameters using [`ALTER SYSTEM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersystem.html).

Comment: Note that this doesn't *persistently* modify the config, it's only for that invocation. You can use `ALTER SYSTEM SET ...` to modify config permanently.